# What is the correct command to use to initialize a repo with more than one mirror reference on a local disk?

Tags: reference, android-source, mirror, repo, git-repo

What is the correct command to use to initialize a repo with more than one mirror reference on a local disk?

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b "branch" --reference="/local/mirror1/dir/aosp" --reference="/local/mirror2/dir/vendordevices"
```

will override reference to /local/mirror2/dir/

Manually editing /.repo/manifests.git/config to include

```
[repo]
/local/mirror2/dir/
```

does not have the desired effect